# AngularJs $scope like a local var

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http

i have some issue.

```
app.controller('groupConfigCntrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', function($http, $scope, $routeParams){

            var id = $routeParams.id,
                info = {};
            $http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
              $scope.info = data;
            });
              console.log($scope.info); 
    });
```

In this case $scope.info is undefined.

```
        $http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
          $scope.info = data;
          console.log($scope.info); 
        });
```

In this case, $scope.info - have some data. Why $scope behave like a local var? Help, it's doesn't work when i try to bind data in views. But in similar controller it works.

Controller what works:

```
app.controller('groupCntrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$routeParams', '$location', function($http, $scope, $uibModal, $routeParams, $location){
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
      $scope.info = data;
    });
})
```

Comment: The function inside .success is a callback. It is called asynchronously after the result has come. Therefore you are seeing the difference. $scope is not behaving like local variable.

Comment: move the statement inside of success callback

Comment: But why in views, i can't use bind with this var, however in similar controller it works great?

Comment: Without define info also, doesn't work.

Comment: var id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.info = {};

Comment: Same result, $scope.info - empty object.

Comment: Your console.log line will display it as an empty object as it is one until the callback method populates it as mentioned by Avinash and in the answers.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time, i solved the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The variable `$scope.info` is defined inside the success callback after the `$http` post is complete.

```
$http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
              $scope.info = data;
              console.log($scope.info); 
            });
```

You cannot access `$scope.info` as it is undefined before the `$http` call.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is there anything wrong? please explain

Comment: Sorry, but it's not me.

Comment: I know. But the people down voting should comment here whats wrong. Well no problem. and have you understand the problem you were facing? Because you just need to define your `$scope.info` inside the `$http` success. You view will be available after the data is defined. :)

Comment: You can just define the `$scope.info` inside success callback and then use `{{$scope.info}}` in your view, by this you can see the delay the `$http` callback makes on receiving the data (if the url of the http call is fine.)

Comment: URL have a fine call. :(

Comment: Have you tried the `{{$scope.info}}` after defining it inside the success callback.

Comment: Solve the problem. data what i bind are not that i get.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `callback`. When you `console.log` in the first case, it is executed before callback is returned and at that time `$scope.info` is `undefined`. Do following to get expected result:

```
app.controller('groupConfigCntrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', function($http, $scope, $routeParams){

            var id = $routeParams.id,
                info = {};
            $http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
              $scope.info = data;
              console.log($scope.info); 
            });

    });
```

You can look into `nexttick` if you want to understand how `callback` works in javascript. Ex : https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the .success() method is a callback. This method is executed asynchronously when the post method is completed.

This means that when you log the output in your first example the $scope.info value may not have been set yet.

Judging by your comments, I suspect the problem that you're having is that the view is not updating when the $scope.info value is set? If this is the case, you need to wrap your callback in the $apply method

```
$http.post("/g/getGroup/", {id: id}).success(function(data) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.info = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the problem you're having is that you cant bind the variable to your view?

Comment: Could you please update your question to reflect this? Is the controller you're showing us the current code you're using?